# Google is indexing post actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seo

I have developed an ASP.NET MVC 5 website that uses jQuery and ajax requests to pull and post data. Google's crawlers found my POST action urls in Javascript code and tried to index them.

In Webmaster Tools I see a lot of errors like that `/Account/Login` with a 500 error response because obviously a name and a password were not provided. How can I solve this problem? I don't want any crawl error, but I don't know how to say to Google not to follow these urls.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Google's instructions](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=en&ref_topic=6061961) to create a [robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) file, which is a request to a search engine to not index.

A sample robots.txt to put in the root of your domain may look like this:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /path/to/my/post/url
```

Comment: So I can't write any directive directly on the POST action... I have to create and mantain this robots.txt, right?

Comment: @Alessandro, I believe so, yes.